# to .append with jQuery and get current index()

Tags: jquery, indexing, append

I have problem to get current index size when I add a div with jQuery

**HTML:**

```html
<div>
    <p>1</p>
</div>

<button>Add</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```js
$("button").live("click",function() {
    var index = $("div").index()+1;
    $("div").append('<p>'+index+'</p>');
});
```

Playground: http://jsfiddle.net/uZwWg/

Must I use the `each` function or is there another solution?

Comment: My fail ever ! Forgot `p` selector

Comment: (+1) And an additional +1 also ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZwWg/2/)**

You should point to the children element to get the desired index 
and use `+2` (index is *zero* based) as you're already starting with `1`

```
$("button").on("click",function() {
    var index = $("div p").index() +2;
    $("div").append('<p>'+index+'</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This will add a div with an incremented number on each click:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var index = $("div p").index()+1;
    $("div").append('<p>'+(index+1)+'</p>');
});​
```

Comment: The `.index()` function returns the index of the **first** matched element relevant to its siblings, not the last one, so I'm not sure if this will work.

Comment: Work for sure, I called indexed of `div` not `div p` :(